# OCR using google-cloud-vision - Result does not contain uni characters for Polish, German, etc

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use OCR feature in Google Vision API but not able to receive expected result. I expect to see ü for German and ć, ń, ó, ś, ź, ł, ę, ą for Polish in the results. Is there a way I can do it?

Obtained text does not contain uni characters for many languages: Polish, German. But this languages in the list of supported languages and language was detected correctly.

[image]

I use drag&drop option here https://cloud.google.com/vision/ and CloudVision Android Sample. Thank you for any advices.

Comment: Hi, you may try to set "languageHints". 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.
For gitting UNI characters in the result you need to set **[LanguageHints](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#ImageContext)**.

For Java it will be:

```
ImageContext imageContext = new ImageContext();
List<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
languages.add("pl");
imageContext.setLanguageHints(languages);
annotateImageRequest.setImageContext(imageContext);
```

Now I have ć, ń, ó, ś, ź, ł, ę, ą for Polish in the results.